# Two buttons matching parent side by side in Android (xml)

Tags: android, xml, button, styling

I am currently toying around with android and making a little bit of a test app just to try coding one.  I'm sure there's an easy way to do this but i can't figure it out.  I want two buttons to be on the bottom of the screen. But, i want one to be on the left side, and one on the right side, with space in the middle.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this perhaps?

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

  <Button
  android:id"@+id/left_button"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
  android:text="Left"/>

  <Button
  android:id"@+id/right_button"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
  android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
  android:text="Right"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: thaaaaank you it was the android:text that i didn't remember i knew there was an easy way just couldn't remember the syntax

Answer (score 1):

You need to give android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" to align left and android:layout_alignParentRight="true" to align right.

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<Button
android:id"@+id/left_button"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:text="Left"/>

<Button
android:id"@+id/right_button"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
android:text="Right"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using either `LinearLayout`, `TableLayout` or `RelativeLayout`. [Try it](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout-objects.html)... it's not that hard.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a linear layout (inside your linerlayout which is created by default when your creating layout)
2. Edit your new linear layout

   ```
   android:layout_gravity="bottom"
   android:orientation="horizontal"
   android:gravity="center"
   ```
3. Add two buttons inside linearlayout (add text/size also)
4. Optional: add both button margin_layout: 10dip

   ```
   android:layout_margin="10dip"
   ```

That should do.